# watchOS DNS problems on the target device, but simulation runs perfectly

Tags: ios, swift, dns, cocoapods, watchos-2

I got stuck with an application (rss reader) with cocoapods running absolutely fine in the simulator, but failing on the target device (watchOS 4.2 based).

The RSS feed sources are valid. - Proof: They're running OK on the simulator.

Here is the console output when running on the target device:

```
    Session activated: 2
2018-03-01 22:15:20.498785+0100 THMReader WatchKit Extension[326:81502] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
2018-03-01 22:15:21.503717+0100 THMReader WatchKit Extension[326:81502] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
2018-03-01 22:15:22.509594+0100 THMReader WatchKit Extension[326:81502] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
2018-03-01 22:15:23.516451+0100 THMReader WatchKit Extension[326:81502] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:8 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
2018-03-01 22:15:23.516874+0100 THMReader WatchKit Extension[326:81502] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)
2018-03-01 22:15:23.529698+0100 THMReader WatchKit Extension[326:81502] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x1669aaa0]: 10:-72000 Err(-65563)
2018-03-01 22:15:23.570373+0100 THMReader WatchKit Extension[326:81492] Task . HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [10:-72000])
2018-03-01 22:15:23.571235+0100 THMReader WatchKit Extension[326:81492] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1009
```

It seems like the dns service get locked?

```
nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked
```

How could I fix this issue to also run the code on the target device?

Comment: Adding: I am using FeedKit from Nuno Dias

Comment: Something might have changed with later versions od watchOS with regard to IP access rights:  https://www.bountysource.com/issues/52538221-apple-watch-sandbox